# Enlarging a rectangle around its origin, to fit a containing rectangle, but the rectangle must be moved

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

**EDIT:** The math was easy/as expected. The bug was in a programming error related to HTML/CSS. Sorry everyone, thank you.

I am coding a mobile UI where there is a view of a small card. When clicked, the card expands from its corner, to fit the view.

Like so: 
[image: card expand]

Coding wise, this is a two-step process. The steps happen at the same time.

**Step 1** is to calculate and then scale the small rectangle to the size of the viewport of the mobile device.

I do this by scaleValueX = viewportWidth / cardwidth, and then scaleValueY = viewportHeight / cardHeight

Then I basically use a function that automatically will scale(X,Y) with the data calculated previously. This scales it from its origin.

**Step 2** is a result of the fact that the card expands from around its "origin" and so it by no means is lined up with the viewport dimensions, and it needs to be translated across the view just right, so that the entire expanded card is covering 100% of the screen. Using print statements, I have verified that I am arriving at Step 2 with no flaws in the sizing of my expanded card.

I have spent all of tonight drawing it out on paper and testing in code, and just spent 30 minutes basically guess-and-checking basic operations that might   lead to a formulaic way to solve how to figure out how to translate this.

Anyway, I am asking here instead of StackOverflow because this is to me a problem I am facing due to my limited knowledge of math, and I just want to check what way I am supposed to approach a problem like this.. I will have more animations that the difficulty will be in doing the math on paper. I thought it would be very easy actually to do these 2D animations -- and Step 1 was very easy (I think) -- but now I'm actually finding this very mystifying as to what sort of drawing might yield the insight to come up with an algebraic expression to solve the translation formula.

Edit: Note that the black circle happens to be on the drawing but has no relevance to this problem. The card is marked by a1 b1 c1 d1 in the before state, and a2 b2 c3 d2 in the after state.

Comment: @user341050 Of the card, as best as I can tell it scales the X an equal amount left and right, and then scales the Y equal amounts up and down. It does it all at the same time so it gives it the appearance that the rectangle is expanding from an origin at its very center. If that's what you were asking?

Comment: Translating means you add the same vector to every point, and if you get one point where it needs to go then the rest will follow. Say $(d_1(X),d_1(Y))$ is the image of point $d_1$ after Step 1, and $(d_2(X),d_2(Y))$ is point $d_2$, where you want it to go. Then the translation is $(x,y) \mapsto (x - d_1(X) + d_2(X), y - d_1(Y) + d_2(Y)).$ Is this what you're asking?